# Ubuntu succefully installed, reboot, then nothing

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad Z475 with AMD APU A6-3400m, 8Gb of RAM, and 128Gb SSD from Sandisk Z400s.

I tried to install the ubuntu from USB.

The SSD is new. So no other OS is being installed in my laptop. I have tried for 3 days to install the ubuntu.

Long strory short, for the first day I tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. After the installation process is done, it asked me to reboot my laptop, and after reboot my laptop, it booted my flashdisk.

So I only have options to:

1. Try ubuntu without installing it
2. Install ubuntu
3. OEM install
4. Check disc

I have tried various ways:

1. From BIOS change my HDD from IDE to AHCI
2. Cleanly install from beginning
3. Install alongside with the other Ubuntu
4. Reinstall
5. Erase ubuntu and reinstall

But nothing was worked. Today I tried using the newer version (16.04 LTS), but the same things happened.

Comment: Is system newer UEFI or older BIOS. If UEFI, are you installing in UEFI boot mode or BIOS boot mode? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred sorry I did not try your suggestion. Finally I used different ubuntu image, I used amd64+mac.iso and with this .iso file, the ubuntu was successfully installed, and I could also reboot into it. So now I can play around with ubuntu. Once again thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, guys. I finally made it, but I need to install the ubuntu with amd64+mac iso. If you encounter the same problem as I faced, then my suggestion go to [Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.4/release/).

For my case, I downloaded the [ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64+mac.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.4/release/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)

Goodluck guys!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to remove the flash disk after installation is complete, otherwise the machine will just keep hitting that first.

Comment: I have tried that attempt. But still it did not work. It turned out that I need to download different .iso image. I need to use ubuntu image for amd64+mac. I have no clue why it is so. Nevertheless, it worked fine for my laptop. Now I can play around with ubuntu. Thanks for commenting.